# Accept parameters of URL in .NET CORE

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new in .NET CORE and I would like if its possible to change the default format for request urls. Let me explain. I have two get method on a controller for get a list and get info of 1 element

```
[Route("api/[controller]/")]
[ApiController]
public class Department : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public string GetDepartamento(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

In order to call these resource u use

```
https://localhost:44309/api/department
https://localhost:44309/api/department/1
```

But I need to use this format not just for this controller but all the controllers

```
GET:https://localhost:44309/api/department
GET:https://localhost:44309/api/department?id=1
POST:https://localhost:44309/api/department (data on the body of http call)
PUT:https://localhost:44309/api/department?id=1 (data on the body of http call)
DELETE:https://localhost:44309/api/department?id=1
```

I'm working over a new project (.net core web application MVC)so Startup and Program files were not modified.

Comment: Hi @Kevtho, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0):

> I have two get method on a controller for get a list and get info of 1 element

> I need to use this format

> `GET:https://localhost:44309/api/department`

> `GET:https://localhost:44309/api/department?id=1`

If you'd like to match request(s) to expected action(s) based on the query string, you can try to implement a custom `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` and apply it to your actions, like below.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CheckQueryStingAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public string QueryStingName { get; set; }
    public bool CanPass { get; set; }
    public CheckQueryStingAttribute(string qname, bool canpass)
    {
        QueryStingName = qname;
        CanPass = canpass;
    }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor action)
    {
        StringValues value;

        routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.TryGetValue(QueryStingName, out value);

        if (QueryStingName == "" && CanPass)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (CanPass)
            {
                return !StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
            }

            return StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
        }
    }
}
```

*Apply it to actions*

```
[HttpGet]
[CheckQuerySting("id", false)]
[CheckQuerySting("", true)]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}

[HttpGet]
[CheckQuerySting("id", true)]
[CheckQuerySting("", false)]
public string GetDepartamento(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

Test Result

[image]